# lodash using map on a deep nested array and object

Tags: javascript, lodash

i'm trying to filter an array and get the phone numbers from an address book using lodash, the structure is something like

```
var obj = {
  'contacts': [{
    'id': 1,
    'displayName': 'John Doe',
    'phonenumbers': [{
      'id': '1',
      'type': 'mobile',
      "pref":false,
      'value': '555-555'
    }, {
      'id': '2',
      'type': 'mobile',
      "pref":false,
      'value': '555-554'
    }]
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'displayName': 'Jane Doe',
    'phonenumbers': [{
      'id': '1',
      'type': 'mobile',
      "pref":false,
      'value': '555-557'
    }]
  }]
}
```

i can try to reach the phone numbers with something like:

```
        lodash.map(
                contacts,
                function(person) {
                    return { id: person.id,
                        displayName: person.displayName,
                        phoneNumbers: [
                            {
                                number: person.phoneNumbers[0].value,
                                type: person.phoneNumbers[0].type}
                        ],
                        photos: person.photos };
                }
            );
```

but when i want to get the 2 and third with person.phoneNumbers[1].value, i get errors when there is no second phone number, is there a way to get them without specifying the position in the array?
the output should be a new array with the id of the contact and the phone numbers and type.

```
var ouptput= {
  'contacts': [{
    'id': 1,
    'phonenumbers': [{
      'type': 'mobile',
      'value': '555-555'
    }, {
      'type': 'mobile',
      'value': '555-554'
    }]
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'phonenumbers': [{
      'type': 'mobile',
      'value': '555-557'
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need lodash for this anymore if you're using es6.

```
contacts.map( ({ id, phonenumbers }) => 
  ({ id, phonenumbers: phonenumbers.map( ({ value, type }) => ({ value, type }) ) })
);
```

And you get the exact output you wanted.

Comment: You don't even need to use ES6 to do this. Although it does make the code shorter and better.

Comment: True, it's mainly a syntax thing. Also: IE > 8.

Comment: @samislimani yeah for simple stuff like this you tend to not really need lodash that often.